# Why doesn't CSS hover work on table rows when the cells inside the rows have class names?

Tags: css, html-table, hover

I am  stuck with this problem so any help would be appreciated. I have a table with several rows. Each cell within the row belongs to a certain class. I use these class names to colour the cells.

Here is one example row from my table:

```
<tr>
     <td class = "summarypage-odd-column">Theme</td>    <td class = "summarypage-odd-column">Q2 2009</td>   <td class = "summarypage-odd-column">Q1 2009</td>
     <td class = "summarypage-even-column">Theme</td>   <td class = "summarypage-even-column">Q2 2009</td>  <td class = "summarypage-even-column">Q1 2009</td>
     <td class = "summarypage-odd-column">Business Area</td>    <td class = "summarypage-odd-column">Q1 2009</td>   <td class = "summarypage-odd-column">Q1 2008</td>
 </tr>
```

I would like to highlight each row when the user moves mouse pointer over any cell in that row. So I used the following CSS code to achieve that.

```
tr:hover {
  background-color: #FFFAF0; color: #000;
}
```

unfortunately it seems because each table data cell has a class name, the hover does not work. But if I remove the class names from data cells, the hover works.

My question is is there any way I can get the hover thing working for the table row, while still having class names for the table data cells inside the row.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try this:

```
tr:hover td {
  background-color: #FFFAF0; color: #000;
}
```

Place this after the existing `td` style declarations to be safe

Comment: mate, you totally nailed it! Thanks. when I first looked at it I thought your solution will apply the back. color only to the data cell the mouse pointer is pointing at and not the whole row (which is what i wanted). But obviously that is not the case. There were some rows like the heading which i did not want to be highlighted so i simple defined another class below ur code and put:
--- tr.summarypage-section-title:hover td{
 background-color: deepskyblue; color: #000;
}
 ---

Comment: @Nick Craver it works, but could you explain why tr:hover does not work?

Comment: @Bear because the html code above needs to be nested in <table> tags.  Once you nest them in table tags the CSS for tr:hover then works at least on Chrome and FF with the class attribute defined.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have rows which have classes and I want hover to work to highlight rows on hover. I tried this solution and messed around with it, but to no avail. Do you have any suggestions? I can't get this to work. By the way I have to use IE8 if that might be the problem

Comment: This only highlight the cell, not the whole row

Answer (score 0):

[This does not happen for me.](http://jsbin.com/osami3/3/edit) Make sure that you're only adding/removing class names when checking if they have an impact, and make sure that the `td`s don't have their own background covering up that of the `tr`.

Comment: hi Matchu, you gave the cells class names but you didn't use those names to format the cells. try adding the following two lines to you 'style' section and see what happens.
 -- 
 td.one{background-color: red}
  td.two{background-color: blue} -- 

This is the prob I am faced with.

Comment: That's right. The `td` tags are on top, so their background color takes precedence. How about having `tr:hover td` as your style?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the !important designator to make sure that your hover style overrides the background defined int he class:

```
tr:hover { 
    background-color: #FFFFAF0 !important;
    color: #000 !important; 
}
```

Interestingly, this won't work for IE6 because that browser only applies hover to a tags.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS instructions within the classname takes precedence over the `<tr>` instructions.

To fix this, use td.summarypage-odd-column:hover, td.summarypage-even-column:hover inside your CSS.

Note: If you're using IE6, the :hover only works on links, i.e. a:hover.

Comment: thanks but 'td.summarypage-odd-column:hover' only highlights each data cell dsnt it? I want the entire row to be highlighted. Nick's answer 'tr:hover td' is the way to go. but if you want to treat a set of cells within the row differently you can use smthin similar to wht u suggest.

For example, not to highlight empty cells: --> tr:hover td.empty-cells{ ...table bk colour here...} <-- will do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `td` background-color overwrites the tr background-color. The solution given by @Nick Craver is the good one.
You must change cells background-color not the row background-color.

```
tr:hover td {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

never put space between

```
tr:hover(space)td
```

I was giving space hence it was working for me.

Comment: Please improve your answer.