# Why does my table tr td:hover only work for the th header row?, not for any other rows?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-tables

I have [this code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPrSU/8) and I would like the rows to highlight when I hover over them. I have tried the usual technique that works for me, but on this one, it only highlights the `th` header row, and not the `table` rows.

[View the code in JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/NPrSU/8)

Basically, I've tried the usual:

```
table tr:hover{background-color: yellow;}
```

But this only highlights the table `tr th` Row only, and not the rows of the table, I have no idea why it's doing this.

[Check out the code in JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/NPrSU/8)

Comment: maybe that will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248875/why-doesnt-css-hover-work-on-table-rows-when-the-cells-inside-the-rows-have-clas

Comment: Can you go into your jsfiddle and remove everything that's not relevant?  Put only your table in the html, remove all css that doesn't apply to it - and so on.  There's just way too much code.

Comment: @AleksG Done, removed all unneeded code, i just put it their incase anything interfered with the code, its cleaned up now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure either why it doesn't work as it is, but removing `td` in `#main_content table tr td` seems to do the job. So change

```
#main_content table tr td
{
    color: #666;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

to

```
#main_content table tr
{
    color: #666;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but this will cause the table cells to lose the border's. Instead all you really want to do is remove that color from the td's and not all the properties.

Comment: Well to clarify things: if you assign a background color to the row(tr) and to its children (td) but only change the row background-color, then obviously the td-color remains unchanged - try assigning background-colors only to TR and not to tds - furthermore, if you use a typical table header, use `<thead> and <tbody>` more good markup is always useful ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify the CSS code, as so:

```
#main_content table tr:hover td
{

        color: #666;
        border-right: 1px solid #eee;
        background-color: #ffcc11;
}
```

the `:hover` is the main thing.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

That's because your `td`'s background color is overriding the tr's background color. So, you need to change the following

```
#main_content table tr td     
{
    color: #666;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}

to 

#main_content table tr td
{
    color: #666;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}

#main_content table tr           // apply the color to the tr instead of the td this way it can get overridden
{
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, change

```
#main_content table tr td
{
        color: #666;
        border-right: 1px solid #eee;
        background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

to

```
#main_content table tr
{
        color: #666;
        border-right: 1px solid #eee;
        background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

as seen in http://jsfiddle.net/jhuntdog/NPrSU/12/embedded/result/

Comment: Yeah but what happens to the borders then ??